# Test REAL credit card #'s and CVV with authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

My client would like to test his application using real credit card #'s and real cvv codes.  We don't want to charge the cards, but we do want the system to act the way it would in production.  Namely, it should validate both the CC # and CVV codes.  Is there a way to do this with authorize.net?  We are currently in "live mode" in the sandbox at https://sandbox.authorize.net.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way to do this with real cards without actually processing them in a live environment. However, you can test your integration, including getting certain CVV responses, using [a developer account](https://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/). See [this thread in their community forums](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Triggering-Specific-Transaction-Responses/td-p/4361) for how to trigger certain results (i.e. declines, CVV mismatches, etc).